# How to use HoloLens 2 Hand Tracking and Near Interaction Input on compatible components in Unity (Near Interaction Grabbable, Manipulation Handler)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

I have some GameObject that have a Near Interaction Grabbable Script and a Manipulation Handler Script that works fine using the HoloLens 1 Gaze + Select Interactions (AirTap + Drag) provided by MRTK. Now, I saw that the MRTK Slate Prefab (https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Slate.html) uses the same scripts that I do, but they're able to use the HoloLens 2 Hand Tracking and Near Interaction Input. I am wondering if they're a way for me to support these gestures and if so, how? I'm also wondering if I need to change the MRTK Input settings in Unity or if I'm missing something else!

In Unity, I tried to change the MRTK Input Settings to use the one they were using in their Example Scene (https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html#open-and-run-the-handinteractionexamples-scene-in-editor) because they have the HoloLens 2 Input and Interactions, but did not manage to get it to work.

To make it clearer, is how the [cursor behave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Kuw.png) when I get close to the title bar that I want to grab it and here's the [MRTK Script Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4tGT.png).

I'd love it if I could use the same Input Systems that they're using in Unity and their Example Scene so that I could make the Hand Interaction works, since I'm theoretically using HoloLens 2 compatible scripts.

Comment: Can you trim this down to one question? It will make it easier for someone who knows the answer to provide a complete solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, are you using the MRTK RC2 release, latest mrtk_development, or an earlier release? There used to be a bug in an earlier version where could you not grab a collidable if there was a NearInteractionTouchable near the grabbable.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow!

To make an object grabbable near, you need to make sure that you have both a near interaction grabbable AND a collidable on the same object you want to grab. For example, here's the configuration to make a cube movable. You can read more about this at the [ManipulationHandler documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_ManipulationHandler.html)

[image]